# Subscript out of range, why?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing macro that makes some kind of a table based on data from spreadsheet, and I get subscript out of range on a specific line. Below in the code I marked the exact place(1) where it occured. I tried putting another variable e.g l and do it like this l=i and then below i=l-1 but it's just the same as it was.

```
Sub testo()

    Const cSheet As String = "Procenty"   ' spreadsheet name
    Const cRange As String = "A2:D71"     ' range
    Const cel As Long = 6             
    Const cCol As Variant = "A"           

    Dim vntS As Variant   ' tablica from
    Dim vntT As Variant   ' tablica to
    Dim i As Integer      ' row counter
    Dim emptyRow As Long  ' first empytrow



    Dim kom As Double, komz As Double, kredyt As Double

    Dim roz As Double, komr As Double, komn As Double nadplata
    Dim napis As String 
    Dim dz As Date, dw As Date 

    napis = "null"


    vntS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSheet).Range(cRange)

    'changing table size
    ReDim vntT(1 To UBound(vntS), 1 To cel)


    kredyt = 0
    For i = 1 To UBound(vntS)
If vntS(i, 1) = "" Then
dw = Date
Else
dz = vntS(i, 1)
End If

        ' values to variables
        dz = vntS(i, 1)
        komz = vntS(i, 2)
        dw = vntS(i, 3)
        kom = vntS(i, 4)

        '*******************************
        ' Start
        '*******************************

        If kom = komz Then

            vntT(i, 1) = dz
            vntT(i, 2) = komz
            vntT(i, 3) = dw
            vntT(i, 4) = kom


        ElseIf komz > kom Then

              vntT(i, 1) = dz
            vntT(i, 2) = komz
            vntT(i, 3) = dw
            vntT(i, 4) = kom
            i = i + 1
            komr = komz - kom
            vntT(i, 1) = dz
            vntT(i, 2) = komr
            vntT(i, 3) = dw
            vntT(i, 4) = kom
           i = i - 1

        ElseIf komz < kom Then

          vntT(i, 1) = dz
            vntT(i, 2) = komz
            vntT(i, 3) = dw
            vntT(i, 4) = kom
            i = i + 1
            komn = kom - komz
            vntT(i, 3) = dw <------- (1) here is the subscript out of range
            vntT(i, 4) = komn
            i = i - 1


       ' ElseIf komz > kom And dz >= dw Then
       ' roz = Abs(dz - dw)
        'komr = komz - kom
           ' vntT(i, 5) = napis
           ' kredyt = kredyt - komr

       ' ElseIf komz < kom And dw <= dz Then
      '  komn = kom - komz
       '     vntT(i, 5) = komn
        '    kredyt = kredyt + komn
       ' ElseIf komz < kom And dz < dw Then
       ' roz = Abs(dz - dw)
        '    vntT(i, 5) = procent(komz, roz)
        '    kredyt = kredyt - procent(komz, roz)
        End If

        '*******************************
        ' end
        '*******************************

    Next


    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSheet)

        emptyRow = .Columns(cCol).Find("*", , xlFormulas, _
                xlWhole, xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Row + 1
        'emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Columns(cCol)) + 1
        ' writing table out
        .Cells(emptyRow, cCol).Resize(UBound(vntT), UBound(vntT, 2)) = vntT
        .Cells(emptyRow, cCol) = kredyt
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You're incrementing and decrementing `i` in a `For` loop, this often causes unexpected results.  My guess is that `i` either became `0` or became greater than the bounds of the `vntT` array.

Comment: Well so far I deduced it BUT I don't know how to fix it and that is why I posted this question here.

Comment: Start by removing the lines that play with the value of `i`. Use something like `vntT(i + 1, 3) = dw` instead. You may also need to loop `i` to `1` less than the maximum. i.e. `For i = 1 To UBound(vntS) - 1` or `ReDim` `vntT` to be one larger: `ReDim vntT(1 To UBound(vntS) + 1, 1 To cel)`